# Can higher dimension simplex occur in a triangulation of a $k$-sphere?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplex, simplicial-complex

A $k$-simplex is a convex hull of $k+1$ points (which are called vertices) in general position in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for $k\le n$).
A face of a simplex is a simplex spanned by a subset of its vertex set.
And a collection $C$ of simplices in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called a simplicial complex if every two simplices in $C$ meet, if at all, in a face common to both. The union of all simplices in $C$ is denoted by $||C||$.
A triangulation of a topological space $X$ is a simplicial complex $C$ such that $||C||$ is homeomorphic to $X$.

Then for a triangulation $C$ of a $k$-sphere $S^k$, I am wondering is there a $\ell$-simplex  in $C$ with $\ell>k$? My intuition is that it's impossible. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Sounds like a good job for the Invariance of Domain theorem.

Comment: In a singular triangulation, it is possible. Homeomorphically, as suggested by @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC, it is not possible, since it would imply that the interior is simultaneously $>k$-dimensional and $\leqslant k$-dimensional.